How to add PrometheusRule so we can get only one data in 10 min in TSDB?
Lets assume Prometheus instance is scrapping data each 15 sec
Now I want to add Prometheus Rule something like - max (sum by namespace for cpu data) over last 10 min).

max_over_time for 10 min
sum by (namespace) kube_pod_container_resource_requests{resource="cpu"}
It should add only one entry in TSDB for every 10 min.

So if I will do recorded_metric[1h] then it should return only 6 entries as we want to store only 1 value in each 10 min.
Thanks in advance.

Put it into rule_group with interval: 10m
